# Libel complaint against publishing company d/b/a/ as newspaper

Tags: defamation, libel

A newspaper defamed a Plaintiff. The newspaper is the business name of a publishing company (ie. the publishing company d/b/a/ the newspaper). Can the Plaintiff write the following in his or her complaint?

Libel Count I 
(against newspaper)

*Rather than,*

Libel Count I 
(against publishing company)

Answer (score -2):

### No

Only people can be sued. A business is not a person; a company is.

Comment: Indeed. Assuming that the publishing company is named as a party in the complaint, can a Plaintiff be more specific in the individual counts and refer to the business name as I did above?

Comment: You would certainly mention the newspaper as the place where the libel happened